# How can I properly parse an email address with name?

Tags: parsing, node.js, email-headers

I'm reading email headers (in Node.js, for those keeping score) and they are VARY varied. E-mail addresses in the `to` field look like:

```
"Jake Smart" <jake@smart.com>, jack@smart.com, "Development, Business" <bizdev@smart.com>
```

and a variety of other formats. Is there any way to parse all of this out?

Here's my first stab:

1. Run a `split()` on `-` to break up the different people into an array
2. For each item, see if there's a `<` or `"`.
3. If there's a `<`, then parse out the email
4. If there's a `"`, then parse out the name
5. For the name, if there's a `,`, then split to get Last, First names.

If I first do a split on the `,`, then the `Development, Business` will cause a split error. Spaces are also inconsistent. Plus, there may be more e-mail address formats that come through in headers that I haven't seen before. Is there any way (or maybe an awesome Node.js library) that will do all of this for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a npm module for this - [mimelib](https://github.com/andris9/mimelib) (or mimelib-noiconv if you are on windows or don't want to compile node-iconv)

```
npm install mimelib-noiconv
```

And the usage would be:

```
var mimelib = require("mimelib-noiconv");
var addressStr = 'jack@smart.com, "Development, Business" <bizdev@smart.com>';
var addresses = mimelib.parseAddresses(addressStr);

console.log(addresses);
// [{ address: 'jack@smart.com', name: '' },
//  { address: 'bizdev@smart.com', name: 'Development, Business' }]
```

Comment: Is there perhaps a non-node version of this available? Something that could be used on the front-end?

Comment: There is a FirefoxOS specific version that probably runs in other browsers as well https://github.com/andris9/firemail/blob/master/docs/addressParser.md

Comment: Or for node/js version with code you can port, just use the addressparser module directly: https://npmjs.org/package/addressparser

Comment: The project is deprecated!: https://github.com/andris9/mimelib#readme

Answer (score 3):

The actual formatting for that is pretty complicated, but here is a regex that works. I can't promise it always will work though. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-15

```
const str = "...";
const pat = /(?:"([^"]+)")? ?<?(.*?@[^>,]+)>?,? ?/g;

let m;
while (m = pat.exec(str)) {
  const name = m[1];
  const mail = m[2];

  // Do whatever you need.
}
```

Comment: please declare "m" as a local variable

Answer (score 0):

For something complete, you should port this to JS: http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/RJBS/Email-Address-1.895/lib/Email/Address.pm

It gives you all the parts you need. The tricky bit is just the set of regexps at the start.

Answer (score -1):

I'd try and do it all in one iteration (performance). Just threw it together (limited testing):

```
var header = "\"Jake Smart\" <jake@smart.com>, jack@smart.com, \"Development, Business\" <bizdev@smart.com>";
alert (header);
var info = [];
var current = [];
var state = -1;
var temp = "";
for (var i = 0; i < header.length + 1; i++) {
  var c = header[i];
  if (state == 0) {
    if (c == "\"") {
      current.push(temp);
      temp = "";
      state = -1;
    } else {
      temp += c;
    }
  } else if (state == 1) {
    if (c == ">") {
      current.push(temp);
      info.push (current);
      current = [];
      temp = "";
      state = -1;
    } else {
      temp += c;
    }
  } else {
    if (c == "<"){
      state = 1;
    } else if (c == "\"") {
      state = 0;
    }
  }
}

alert ("INFO: \n" + info);
```

Comment: Does seem to parse the addresses into some other structure, but the resulting structure isn't terribly convenient. I can't distinguish between an address being missing, from the personal part being missing, for example, and it's returning the personal parts at all, which surely it shouldn't.